# jquery bind() binding to unwanted elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, bind, mouseenter

I have a `ul`, each `li` has a row of images, and I am trying to bind a function to each `li` so that on `'mouseenter'` the row of images appears, and on `'mouseout`' the row of images disappears...I call `bind()` on the `div` within each `li` based on a an `#id`, so that they work independently. 
Everything is working, except that the bind function seems to be binding each discrete function to their respective `div`, and then to each subsequent `li` beneath it...not above, though...so as I move the mouse down through the lower list items(which are currently collapsed), the focused row of images flashes in and out...if I have one of the lower rows of images un-collapsed(only one can be un-collapsed at a time), and move the mouse up over the 'above' list items, this glitchy behavior does not occur...

`$menu1` is the `div` within the first `li`...even with just this code (and the other four bind calls commented out) all four rows of images still trigger `$menu1` to fade in and out..

here's the code:

```
$menu1.bind('mouseenter', function(){

$menu1.animate({'opacity':'1.0'});                  

}).bind('mouseleave', function(){ 

$menu1.animate({'opacity':'0.0'}); 

});
```

Ive been trying to sort this out for a couple days now, and my jquery/javascript skills are just not up to snuff it seems...thanks so much for any help.

Comment: I think it will help if you go to http://jsfiddle.net and post a link to your code here.

Comment: Did you try using the `this` keyword inside your functions, and ideally you would be using `on()` this year. Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FjvZs/) ??

Comment: here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/uXnVb/

Comment: i should add im working on this for a friend, who is using some pre-made jquery image gallery slider thing, and there is an extra javascript file that is fully cryptic, and i understand nothing about, and am not sure how it is related, but anyways, im just a bit stumped about this binding functionality that seems to be a little glitchy? and was just wondering if anyone knew of this...sorry for the ignorance and lack of better knowledge...thanks

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that $menu1 is a correct identifier. 
Do you mean `$("#menu1")`?

Comment: $menu1 is a variable i declared using: var $menu1 = $('#menu1');